# Mobile localization strings load from server

Tags: android, ios, localization, internationalization, translation

I'm reformatting the way my team does localization of our Android and iOS apps. It is critical for us to be able to update the strings from the server.
I probably read all SO questions on the topic and understand the downsides and problems. But there is still not too much info on this, so I got a few questions.

1. I saw some JSON localization tools for iOS and Android, they are pretty rudimentary and keep all strings in the memory. Another option is to read from a file every time, but that seems even worse. I know on Android I can also use SQLite, something similar on iOS? What would be the optimal solution in terms of performance?
2. They biggest problem I'm seeing is supporting plurals/genders. The plural logic is especially complicated and different for every language, so if I write a tool I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel. Anyway to reuse the built-in logic?
   Thanks!